# find_if on a string array

Tags: string, foreach, c++

I am finding all strings from an array depending on the first letter:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<string>

int main(){

const std::string strArray[] =  {"an","blau","Bo","Boot","bos","da","Fee","fern","Fest","fort","je","jemand","mir","Mix",
                      "Mixer","Name","neu","od","Ort","so","Tor","Torf","Wasser"};

std::string value = "JNQ";
for_each(value.begin(), value.end(), [strArray](char c){
                  std::string const * iterator = find_if(strArray, strArray+23, [c](std::string str){
                                                    return toupper(str[0]) == c;
                                                 });
                  std::cout<<*iterator<<'\n';
          });

 return 0;
}
```

I get this output:

```
je
Name
an
```

Why is 'an' displayed?
I am using g++ 4.5 on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`iterator` is not valid in 3rd case.

In this case `iterator = strArray + 23` and point to element placed after array.

Look the [fixed code](http://ideone.com/Vh16L).

Comment: @Abhi: `if (iterator != strArray + 23) { std::cout << *itrerator; } else { std::cout << "wrong"; }` --> http://ideone.com/Vh16L

Comment: Hmm. Seems to work. Wouldn't it have been better if find_if just returned null?

Comment: @Abhi This is the way C++ algorithms are designed to work. They *all* return `end` when the item isn't found and using that approach consistently makes code much easier to maintain and understand.

Comment: @Abhi: It is not universal to return null. If you use `std::vector<int>::const_iterator` rather than `SomeClass *` for example then you can not return null. You have to return something else. The next after last is ok.

Comment: To elaborate on Mark's statement, `NULL` usually is a way we represent an object as "invalid", and in this case, `find_if`'s way of marking the return value as invalid is returning `strArray+23`, which isn't null but it's also not an element in the array, so that's "invalid" or "not found". Just compare against `strArray+23` instead of `NULL` and you get the same effect.

Comment: @Robert, great comment. Too good. I was just going to ask what 'end' actually meant.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your code is that you're NOT checking `iterator` against the `end` of the array, before this line:

```
std::cout<<*iterator<<'\n';
```

which should actually be this:

```
if (iterator != (strArray+23))  //print only if iterator != end
     std::cout<<*iterator<<'\n';
```

See this. Its working now.

- http://www.ideone.com/vyqlR

It doesn't print `"an"` anymore.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Others have already told you the iterator is invalid, so I won't repeat that. However, here is a quick type-up of a solution that should work for you. As a side-note, don't use "magic numbers" to represent your array sizes. This is error-prone because if the size of the array changes (i.e. you add another element to it later) then it is easy to forget to update the 23 to 24. Consider this solution:

```
static unsigned const length = sizeof( strArray );
std::string const* end = strArray+length;
std::string const * iterator = find_if(strArray, end, [c](std::string str){
                                  return toupper(str[0]) == c;
                               });
if( iterator != end ) {
    std::cout<<*iterator<<'\n';
}
```

Note I couldn't compile this, as I do not have a C++0x compiler, so consider this pseudo-code if nothing else.

Comment: `length` is actually `sizeof( strArray ) / sizeof( strArray[0] );` because otherwise it counts the size of the pointers.

Comment: @MarkB I thought about that, but since strArray is a static array, I thought `sizeof(strArray)` will return the number of elements in the array, not the number of bytes. Also I think it's an array of `std::string` s, not pointers. However, I haven't done C++ in a while so I could be mistaken. Ultimately the ideal solution is to use `std::vector<std::string>` anyway.

Comment: will that be efficient however?

Comment: @Abhi will what be efficient? Using `std::vector`? Yes. It essentially compiles down to basically the same assembler as it would if you used a regular array, like you're doing. However, efficiency isn't the only benefit. It makes your code more manageable and readable. It also cleans up a lot of boilerplate code and makes using STL algorithms more natural